# wondering about Software Serial Library

Tags: arduino

## software Serial

> I was searching on the internet and i was seeing this Software Serial a lot, i'm wondering what the Software Serial library is used for?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Docs](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial):

> The SoftwareSerial library has been developed to allow serial
>   communication on other digital pins of the Arduino, using software to
>   replicate the functionality (hence the name "SoftwareSerial"). It is
>   possible to have multiple software serial ports with speeds up to
>   115200 bps. A parameter enables inverted signaling for devices which
>   require that protocol.

Suppose that you are using an Arduino Uno which has only one Hardware Serial port and you want to connect it to a GSM Modem which uses a serial port to communicate. And you need to get AT commands from a PC user. So you need two Serial ports. You can use Default Hardware Serial for PC communication and one **Software Serial** for communicating with the Modem. Then simply send and receive AT commands.

There are some limitations for Software Serial like slower baud rate comparing to hardware serial, can't receive data from multiple serials simultaneously, etc.

It is recommended to use Software Serial for boards that don't have enough Hardware Serial ports. So you need to remember that using Hardware Serial always is a better choice.